# How do I implement restore purchase button in ios app if I store subscription info in the database?

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store

I submitted my app to the App Store for review and I received a feedback saying that I need to implement "Restore purchase" button.

I don't understand how I should implement it because my app requires users to sign up and login. And if user buys a subscription I store this information in the database. So basically if user logs in into the app he always gets access to his subscription.

Please advice,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're absolutely right that if user logs into the app then he gets but because of some reasons we can't get user's subscription data at login time and logged user in then he needs to go subscription page and need to make new payments though he already has, so the better way to implement restore button in app at 2 places

**1.** in your subscription page

**2.** login page

**1. in your subscription page**
Maintain a flag some kind of that from your backend and get that flag and show restore button in subscription page instead of showing purchase button after clicking on that user can fetch all the subscription data from his account

**2. Login page**
At the login page you can automatically fetch the user's subscription details with showing loader page with some message for waiting/fetching, etc.

Hope this might help you.